# "NA in INT 64 Error" due to DB Connect change from Local host to RMariaDB

Tags: r, mariadb, r-dbi

We just shifted from a DB Connect from local host to one using SSL tunnel

and we get the error "NA overflow in INT 64"

**previously**

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
       dbname="databse",user='Username',password='password',host='localhost')
```

**Now**

```
con <- dbConnect(
  RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  username="user",
  password="password",
  dbname="database",
  host="servername",
  port=6033,
  ssl.ca="path",
  client.flag=2048
)
```